# IOS SWIFT 2 - display the same alert with different titles in different scene

Tags: ios, swift

i need to display the same alert with different titles in each time
so i want to create a function that takes a string and changes the title of the alert and then display this alert

my question is : where should i create this function ? and how call it from another viewControllers ?

Comment: I would create an extension of UIAlertController and write it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend UIAlertController by implementing your own custom class, then you present this controller where you want it to be presented just changing **title**. Below is the sample code, it works. Hope you will understand the concept.

```
import UIKit

extension UIAlertController {
class func alertControllerWithTitle(title: String, message: String) -> UIAlertController {
    let controller = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)
    controller.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
    return controller
}
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

let someProperty = 0
var alertTitle = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    someMethod()
}

func someMethod() {
    switch someProperty {
    case 0:
        alertTitle = "someProperty is 0"
    case 1:
        alertTitle = "someProperty is 1"
    default:
        alertTitle = "someProperty is default"
    }

    //present alert
    let controller = UIAlertController.alertControllerWithTitle(alertTitle, message: "some message")
    presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function can be created as a stand-alone function (i.e. not part of any struct or class).  It can exist anywhere in the same module as the classes that call it such as the view controllers.  Personally, I would place it in a file on its own (called `<yourFunctionName>.swift`) close to the view controllers, or in a utility file containing similar functions.

Because the function is defined in the same module as the view controllers, it can be called directly by them.

Answer (score 0):

Create a common class , place this function in that class, it should return a configured **UIAlertController** , create a protocol for that function in that common class with the alert function having *Title* as parameter.Conform this protocol to the class you want to display the Alert in, call it by its delegate and present it in a `self.presentViewController(....`.